# Magento - Calling Product Video Attribute into Static Block (can't get video to display - new to php)

Tags: php, magento, static, tabs, block

So I created a new file called getVideo.phtml in my template/catalog/product/view folder and called it into a static block in a custom tab using:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="catalog/product/view/getVideo.phtml"}}
```

In my phtml file I added:

```
<?php 
  $_prodID = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
  $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_prodID );
?>
  <?php if ($_product_video): ?>
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Video') ?></h2>
    <div class="std">
      <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(),
    $_product_video,   'Video') ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

So far there isn't a fatal php error, but the video isn't showing up. The URL from the attribute isn't showing either. Our product attribute in Magento is product_video and there's either a Vimeo or Youtube video link in that attribute text window.

Comment: I can't accept yet because the video still doesn't show up. I don't want someone else using this if its not right.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php 
      $_prodID = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
      $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_prodID );
    ?>
      <?php if ($_product_video): ?>
        <h2><?php echo $this->__('Video') ?></h2>
        <div class="std">
         <?php if($_product->getData('product_video')): ?>
       <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $_product->getData('product_video') ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

**EDIT**

try to change block type

```
{{block type="catalog/product" template="catalog/product/view/getVideo.phtml"}}
```

Let me know if you have any query

Comment: what is your attribute id ?

Comment: product_video is the ID

Comment: I appreciate your continued help, but that still didn't do it. I just get an empty space where the video is supposed to show up.

Comment: have you enter video url in text box ?  and please try to remove cache

Comment: Yes, video url in text box and cache cleared. Is the block type correct?

Comment: Still no. It shows to be good php, but something's getting lost in Magento somewhere. Maybe still not right at block type.

Comment: have you got $_prodID ?

Comment: There's over 6000 of them so I'll need that to be dynamic.